# Html code in body executes after script runs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in Javascript and i'm trying to make an http request to fetch some data and display the results in html. I'm fetching the results and update the html code, but then the html code inside body reloads and shows the default values. My code is,

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function httpGetAsync() {

      var results = new Array(3);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.send();
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

      function processRequest() {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

          // populate here results array

          // i change the value with the following line
          document.getElementById("title_1").innerText = "fetched_value";

        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="search_btn">

    <form id="search_form" method="get" onSubmit="return httpGetAsync()">

      <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
      <input type="submit" value="search" class="search_button">

    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="one">

    <p id="title_1">default</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

The 'title_1' changes its text to 'fetched_value' but it then reloads and becomes 'default' again. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No need to use XMLHttpRequest directly, try to use the new `fetch` library, which should be working in all current browsers (this excludes Internet Explorer, but that browser is end of life anyhow)

Comment: @Icepickle But usually you still have to support it...

Comment: @Justinas No, not really, alternatives are simply the mark, we cannot let the world stand still like we did for support for Internet Explorer 6 years ago. Theoretically we could say Internet Explorer 11 should be supported till 2020 when Microsoft drops support for Windows 7, but that really stops innovation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `onSubmit` does not receive `false`. Simply add `return false` to `httpGetAsync` end

```
function httpGetAsync() {
  var results = new Array(3);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.addEventListener(
      "readystatechange",
       function processRequest() {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("title_1").innerText = "fetched_value";
          }
       },
       false);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action on submit, which is to use the "action" attribute on the form element to reload the page (if it's not present the current page is reloaded).

```
function httpGetAsync(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```